# WCF Test Client not working with VS 2010 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 64-bit, wcftestclient

I am unable to use the WCF Test Client.  I always get the following error.

```
Error: Cannot load reference assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'    
Cannot load file C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs for more Information.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies.
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I'm not having any luck finding a solution on google.  I'm hoping that the stackOverflow hive brain can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to add the runtime version setting in your app.config file's `<configuration>` element:

```
<startup>
  <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

Comment: Thanks.  that's it.  I've got version v4.0 rather than v4.0.30319. What about the sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" attribute?  Is it required?  Does it need to be changed as well?

Comment: V4.0 is actually v4.0.30319. I'm not sure about the sku attribute. Was the error resolved by adding the runtime version to the app.config?